# I am looking for how to do the two (BFS, DFS) searches for my 8 puzzle. I'm so close to done

Tags: c, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I've linked the code here..I just don't feel like I understand the search algorithms. I haven't really tried to attempt them, but I know that I don't have to do a thing else. I feel as though this is too simple for me to understand.

When I read on Breadth-First Search, I do understand that I have to search the rows before I move down a level on the tree (and same for depth first moving down), but how would that be coded? I'm just stumped.

Basically, this is an 8-Puzzle using Glut/OPENGL, where the computer does the search for you, and is supposed to output the moves to said user. The blank will ALWAYS start in the middle. I save the order in an array, and then need to output the moves. The thing I am stumped on is the search itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>                         // standard C libraries
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>                       // GLUT library
#include "cs_graphics_setup.h"             // Header for CS4250/5250/6250 courses


// Constants
#define WINDOW_XS 25                       // Window size
#define WINDOW_YS 256
#define WINDOW_NAME "Sliding Box Game"     // Window name
#define FONT_10 GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10 // font size to 10
#define FONT_24 GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24 // font size to 24
#define ANI_MSEC 10                        // gap between frames


// Structures
typedef struct pt
{
    GLfloat x, y;
} MyPoint;


// Global Variables
MyPoint bottomLeftPt;

int xside = 80;
int yside = 80;
int innerx = 70;
int innery = 70;
int i, j, temp, v;

int arrayNumRand[9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8};

//multidimensional array that holds the x-coordinate of the big square, the
//y-coordinate of the big square, and the number that is to be displayed.
int arrayCoord[9][2] =
{
    {8, 168},
    {88, 168},
    {168, 168},
    {8, 88},
    {88, 88},
    {168, 88},
    {8, 8},
    {88, 8},
    {168, 8}
};

//int goUp = 0;  // 0- go up, 1- come down

// Function prototypes
void display_func(void);
void keyboard_func(unsigned char c, int x, int y);
//void animation_func(int val);
void drawSquareFn(int, int, int, int, int);
void display_num(int, int, int);


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    init_setup(WINDOW_XS, WINDOW_YS, WINDOW_NAME);
    //initial testing of arrayNumRand randomization
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i <9; i++)
    {
        j = (rand() %8)+1;
        if(j != 4 && i != 4)
        {
            temp = arrayNumRand[i];
            arrayNumRand[i] = arrayNumRand[j];
            arrayNumRand[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i <9; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d", arrayNumRand[i]);
    }
    glutDisplayFunc(display_func);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard_func);
    //glutTimerFunc(ANI_MSEC, animation_func, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 1;
}   // end of main()


void display_func(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.50, 78.0, 139.0, 0.0); // background color (purple)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);         // clearing the buffer not to keep the color
    for(v = 0; v <9; v ++)
    {
        drawSquareFn(arrayCoord[v][0], arrayCoord[v][1], xside, yside, v);
    }
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();                    // double buffering
}   // end of display_func()



void keyboard_func(unsigned char c, int x, int y)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        /*case 'b' :
        case 'B' :
            //breadth_first_search function

            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;

        case 'd' :
        case 'D' :
            //depth_first_search function

            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;*/
    case 'i' :
    case 'I' :
        for(i = 0; i <9; i++)
        {
            j = (rand() %8)+1;
            if(j != 4 && i != 4)
            {
                temp = arrayNumRand[i];
                arrayNumRand[i] = arrayNumRand[j];
                arrayNumRand[j] = temp;
            }
            display_func();
        }
        for(i = 0; i <9; i++)
        {
            printf(" %d", arrayNumRand[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 'Q' :
    case 'q' :
        printf("Good Bye !\n");
        exit(0);                 // terminates the program
    }  // end of switch
}   // end of keyboard_func()


/*void animation_func(int val)
{
int moveGap = 5;

if( goUp == 0 )
{
    bottomLeftPt.x += moveGap;
    bottomLeftPt.y += moveGap;

    if( bottomLeftPt.x+recLength > WINDOW_XS)
    {
        bottomLeftPt.x -= moveGap;
        bottomLeftPt.y -= moveGap;

        goUp = 1;
    }
    else if( bottomLeftPt.y+recHeight > WINDOW_YS)
    {
        bottomLeftPt.x -= moveGap;
        bottomLeftPt.y -= moveGap;

        goUp = 1;
    }
}
else // goUp = 1
{
    bottomLeftPt.x -= moveGap;
    bottomLeftPt.y -= moveGap;

    if( bottomLeftPt.x < 50)
    {
        bottomLeftPt.x += moveGap;
        bottomLeftPt.y += moveGap;

        goUp = 0;
    }
    else if( bottomLeftPt.y < 50)
    {
        bottomLeftPt.x += moveGap;
        bottomLeftPt.y += moveGap;

        goUp = 0;
    }
}

glutPostRedisplay();
glutTimerFunc(ANI_MSEC, animation_func, 0);
}//end animation_func*/

//beginning of drawSquare Function to create the two nested squares and place the     number on the board.
void drawSquareFn(int x, int y, int xside, int yside, int num)
{
    // draw a rectangle
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);           // setting pen color (black)
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glVertex2i(x+xside, y);
    glVertex2i(x+xside, y+yside);
    glVertex2i(x, y+yside);
    glEnd();
    // draw the outline of rectangle
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);           // setting pen color (black)
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glVertex2i(x+xside, y);
    glVertex2i(x+xside, y);
    glVertex2i(x+xside, y+yside);
    glVertex2i(x+xside, y+yside);
    glVertex2i(x, y+yside);
    glVertex2i(x, y+yside);
    glVertex2i(x,y);
    glEnd();
    x += 5;
    y += 5;
    if(arrayNumRand[num] != 0)
    {
        // draw inner rectangle
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);           // setting pen color (black)
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(x, y);
        glVertex2i(x+innerx, y);
        glVertex2i(x+innerx, y+innery);
        glVertex2i(x, y+innery);
        glEnd();
        //// draw the outline of rectangle
        //glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);         // setting pen color (black)
        //glBegin(GL_LINES);
        //  glVertex2i(x, y);
        //  glVertex2i(x+innerx, y);
        //  glVertex2i(x+innerx, y);
        //  glVertex2i(x+innerx, y+innery);
        //  glVertex2i(x+innerx, y+innery);
        //  glVertex2i(x, y+innery);
        //  glVertex2i(x, y+innery);
        //  glVertex2i(x,y);
        //  glEnd();
        x += 23;
        y += 23;
        //new x value, new y-value, and the number listed above and decide upon color display_num
        display_num(x, y, num);
    }
}

void display_num(int newx, int newy, int newnum)
{
    int points[10];
    int i = 0, j;
    int pos;
    int is_negative = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        points[j] = ' ';
    }
    if(newnum < 0)
    {
        is_negative = 1;
        newnum *= -1;
    }
    while(newnum > 9)
    {
        points[i] = newnum % 10;
        newnum = newnum / 10;
        i += 1;
    }
    points[i] = 1;
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    pos = newx;
    if(is_negative == 1)
    {
        glRasterPos2i(pos, newy);
        glutBitmapCharacter(FONT_24, '-');
        pos += glutBitmapWidth(FONT_24, '-');
    }
    glRasterPos2i(pos, newy);
    glutBitmapCharacter(FONT_24, (char)(arrayNumRand[newnum]+48));
    pos += glutBitmapWidth(FONT_24, (char)(arrayNumRand[newnum]+48));
}

void breadthFirstSearch()

void depthFirstSearch()
{
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the FAQ. We are not here to scan your code for errors, but for answering questions concerning programming. Please ask a question so we can answer **something**.

Comment: This is a great candidate question for Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, guys! I have no really large errors, and am not looking for that kind of help. I just am stumped on this search algorithm.

Comment: @SauceMaster It doesn't belong there. The OP's wording `and is supposed to output the moves to said user` and `but how would that be coded` clears that this isn't working as intended. It belongs to SO although after some editing. Next time please flag the question to be migrated if you think it needs to be moved. It avoids cross-posting.

Comment: @user2605141 Your [question on codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28793/8-puzzle-search-algorithm-help) was put on hold as it wasn't working. Working code belongs there. Non-working belongs here. BUT be aware that people here would answer a specific question. At present **this question is too vague** to be answered. What you need to do is to ask a specific question. Perhaps you can point to a part of your code and ask what exactly isn't working.

Comment: @AseemBansal: Good call on the migration.  Whenever someone tells us they were referred to CR (but without a migration), I feel hesitant about believing that the post really didn't belong here.

Comment: @Jamal If the question didn't belong here it would have been alosed already. SO has much higher traffic than codereview. It just needs editing and clarification to be answered. Maybe a language tag too. I'll add that.

Answer (score 0):

The tree you want to traverse is the tree of board states.  This will be an *implicit* tree:  You will not construct a tree data structure and fill it up with boards.  Each node in the tree is one position of all of the tiles on the board.  Your root node is the board with 8 randomly arranged tiles around the perimeter and one blank in the center.  There's no need to have a tree data structure to traverse because you can easily compute the children of each state just by knowing the state.  From the root you have 4 children (each of the side tiles sliding into the hole).  Each of those has only 3 children (due to the edge of the board).  Some moves will create cycles (e.g. undoing your very first move in your second move) which you will want to avoid.

If you imagine this tree (without cycles) then the nodes of the tree are all of the other board states.  Some of those states are the solution to the puzzle.  From any one of those solution nodes the set of moves is just the path from the root through the tree to the goal node.

For a puzzle of that size you can probably just search directly to the goal.  For more complex problems (e.g. a 256x256 sliding tile puzzle, or more complex games like chess) you will not be able to "see" the endgame.  In those cases you will have to have a scoring function to evaluate whether you are getting better or worse.  Then you will navigate through the tree to promising areas that are close enough for you to see the goal state and find the answer.